# TextFieldStyle in Libgdx

Tags: java, android, fonts, libgdx

Im trying to implement a different font than the default one using TextFieldStyle as I´ve been told. It´s inside a textbox that I want to change the font. But have yet not manage to do it.

This is the class itself:

```
public class StoneScreen implements Screen {

OrthographicCamera camera;
final TombStone game;

//Textures and art.
public Texture background, sdStone, arrowBack;
public Sprite backgrounds;

//TextField´s stuff
private Stage stage;
private Skin skin;
ImageButton btnArrow;




public StoneScreen(TombStone gam)    {
    this.game = gam;



    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 136, 204);

    game.assets.load();
    loadStandard();





}

public void loadStandard(){
    background = game.assets.background;
    sdStone = game.assets.sdStone;
    //backgrounds = Assets.backgrounds;
}



@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    //Recieves the screen width and height
    float gameHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float gameWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();


    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);


    game.batch.begin();
    Gdx.app.log("X", "FPS:" + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());



    game.batch.draw(background,0,0, 136, 204);

    game.batch.draw(sdStone, 40, 20, 70, 110);

    //SpriteBatch batcher = (SpriteBatch)stage.getBatch();


    game.batch.end();

    stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    stage.draw();
}



@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {



    BitmapFont textFont;

    FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("NothingYouCouldDoBold.ttf"));
    FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 12;
    textFont = generator.generateFont(parameter);



//String text = Gdx.app.getPreferences("prefs").getString("text", "Default text if missing");
//String txtArea = Gdx.app.getPreferences("prefs").getString("text", "Default text if missing");
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");

Skin skin = new Skin();
Skin textSkin = new Skin();
skin.add("font", textFont);

stage = new Stage();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("uiskin.json"));

TextFieldStyle textstyle = new TextFieldStyle();
textstyle.font = textSkin.getFont("textFont");


final TextArea textArea = new TextArea(prefs.getString("textArea", "Enter text:"), skin);
textArea.setX(500);
textArea.setY(500);
textArea.setWidth(270);
textArea.setHeight(270);
textArea.setMaxLength(50);

final TextField textField = new TextField(prefs.getString("textField", "Enter name:"), textstyle);


    textField.setX(500);
    textField.setY(750);
    textField.setMaxLength(20);
    //textField.setWidth(450);
    //textField.setHeight(200);
    textField.setSize(400, 200);




    //String text = Gdx.app.getPreferences("prefs").getString("text", "Default text if missimg");
    //TextField textField = new TextField(text, skin);

    //Backbutton 
            ImageButtonStyle styleTwo = new ImageButtonStyle();
            TextureRegionDrawable arrowImage = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture("arrowLeft.png")));
            styleTwo.up = skin.newDrawable(skin.newDrawable(arrowImage));
            styleTwo.down = skin.newDrawable(skin.newDrawable(arrowImage));

    btnArrow = new ImageButton(styleTwo);

    btnArrow.setSize(150, 150);
    btnArrow.setPosition(450, 10);

    stage.addActor(textArea);
    stage.addActor(textField);
    stage.addActor(btnArrow);


    //Backbutton takes us back to mainmenu
            btnArrow.addListener(new ChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
                    game.setScreen(new MainScreen(game));
                    //Saves the entered text.

                    Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("preferences");
                    prefs.putString("textField", textField.getText());
                    prefs.putString("textArea", textArea.getText());
                    prefs.flush();
                }


            });

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

And the important part of this code is inside the Show() class. Where I´ve had no success with it. I get error saying :

```
09-20 17:26:22.606: D/dalvikvm(17329): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.progrmor.tombstone.android-25/libgdx-freetype.so 0x42a968d0
09-20 17:26:22.606: D/dalvikvm(17329): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.progrmor.tombstone.android-25/libgdx-freetype.so 0x42a968d0
09-20 17:26:22.606: D/dalvikvm(17329): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.progrmor.tombstone.android-25/libgdx-freetype.so 0x42a968d0, skipping init
09-20 17:26:22.887: W/dalvikvm(17329): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4189dda0)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 30481
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329): Process: com.progrmor.tombstone.android, PID: 17329
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329): com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: No com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont registered with name: textFont
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.get(Skin.java:145)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.getFont(Skin.java:175)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.progrmor.tombstone.screens.StoneScreen.show(StoneScreen.java:144)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.progrmor.tombstone.screens.MainScreen$1.changed(MainScreen.java:142)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ChangeListener.handle(ChangeListener.java:28)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.notify(Actor.java:174)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor.fire(Actor.java:139)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button.setChecked(Button.java:112)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button$1.clicked(Button.java:86)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:89)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:57)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:342)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidInput.processEvents(AndroidInput.java:382)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:413)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
09-20 17:26:22.887: E/AndroidRuntime(17329):    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
09-20 17:26:27.111: E/AndroidGraphics(17329): waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

so.. what can I might be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
textstyle.font = textSkin.getFont("textFont");
```

you try to get the font with name `textFont` from the skin `textSkin`.

But previously you added the font with a **different name** `font` to a **different  skin**:

```
Skin textSkin = new Skin();
skin.add("font", textFont);
```

==> It won't find your BitmapFont

---

A possible solution is to just get rid of that `textSkin` since you anyway don't add anything to it and do the following instead:

```
//Skin textSkin = new Skin(); // remove this
skin.add("textFont", textFont);
```

//...

```
textstyle.font = skin.getFont("textFont");
```